# MySQL - Error code 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql

I did check other posts. Change timeout value...does not help. its something with the server. It seems each time if I trying to insert sth out range, the server just collapse. Its my localhost, Server on my own computer.

Tried to drop a table or other things. None of the code would work.

Restart the computer would work again, but I'd rather not to to that each time I run into problem.

None of the code in Workbench would work, all come back with Error code 2013...

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'total_revenue' at row 1
23:02:40    DROP TABLE `a_share`.`income_statement` Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  30.000 sec
23:03:51    DROP TABLE `a_share`.`income_statement` Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  30.000 sec
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: None of the solution posted online work

Comment: yeah, i know change timeout value...Nope, no help.

Comment: which server version you are using ? what is size of the table you are dropping ?

Comment: table size about 163kb. 
MySQL Server 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Nerver mind. I found solution.

The server crashed on errors, changing any preference would not help.

you gota press WINDOWS + R

and type in Services.msc

Find MySQL80

right click to reboot the server.

Comment: That's just rebooting the MySQL server. Are you able to do `DROP` or other operation after rebooting again? And does the problem repeat after a while? If it does happen again, simply rebooting the service time and time again is not enough. You need to find out what's causing the MySQL to crash.

Comment: The problem would show up again when I insert values that a greater than originally setted. For example if i have 123456.1234 and insert into SQL, the value it accept should be DECIMAL(5,3), the problem comes out.

Comment: After that, None of the code would work.

Comment: oh...the only thing that works is -- USE xxx

Comment: Try checking the table that you're inserting into by running `CHECK TABLE tablename`. If it returns with `error` or `corrupt` result, run `REPAIR TABLE tablename`. If it return `Ok` try renaming the table to `tablename_old` and create a new one then do the `INSERT` again. If it return `table doesn't exists in engine`, that's a worry though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you run `CHECK TABLE tablename` and it return `Ok`, then try renaming the table to `tablename_old` and create a new one then do the `INSERT` again.